# Constructing a torus with regular tetrahedral of same size

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tetrahedral torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19386/tetrahedral-torus)

Assume now, i have many regular tetrahedral of the same size and i would stick one to another face to face. Is it possible to form a cycle like a ring, i.e. sticking the last tetrahedral to one introduce at the very begining and forming a cycle?

What i have thought is that i know the position of vertex of a new tetrahedral when sticking it on the face of the previous one, it just like reflection, and i can find it by matrices easily.